# node js in apache

Tags: php, apache, serverside-javascript

I searched a lot and found out that `node.js` does not work on `apache`.

Is there any other alternatives for that?

Main idea behind this is use of `server-side` javascript on Apache.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://readwrite.com/2010/12/23/how-to-run-apache-and-nodejs may be it will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node.js` *is* a webserver. It listens on a port, accepts incoming request, and serves responses. Apache is a webserver as well. It listens on a port, accepts incoming requests, but depending on the handlers available may send the request to php, perl, or any cgi to render an output.

What you can do, though, is have node.js listen to port 8081, or anything else, and have Apache listen on port 80. Incoming requests on `http` (port 80) can be proxied to the node.js port.